# C++ - Buffer combining adding extra empty values

Tags: c++, buffer, memcpy

I am trying to fill two buffers, an index buffer object and a vertex buffer object in C++.

```
// Create the IBO and VBO data
GLushort* iboData = new GLushort[polyProcessed * 3];
Vertex* vboData = new Vertex[vertProcessed];

int iboPos = 0;
int vboPos = 0;

// Create the VBO and IBO
for(int i = 0; i < fragMap[0x36]; i++)
{
    // Copy the data to the IBO
    memcpy(iboData + iboPos, zmeshes[i].indices, zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3 * sizeof(GLushort));//sizeof(*zmeshes[i].indices));

    // Advance the position
    iboPos += zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3 * sizeof(GLshort);

    // Copy the data to the VBO
    memcpy(vboData + vboPos, zmeshes[i].vertices, zmeshes[i].numVert * sizeof(Vertex));//sizeof(*zmeshes[i].vertices));

    // Advance the position
    vboPos += zmeshes[i].numVert * sizeof(Vertex);

    errorLog.writeSuccess("Build log: VBO size %i VBO pos %i IBO size %i IBO pos %i", zmeshes[i].numVert * sizeof(Vertex), 
                          vboPos, zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3 * sizeof(GLshort), iboPos);
}
```

It's simply getting the size of the data to be copied, copying it, and then advancing the position (where to put the next data in the buffer).

I get an output like this:

```
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 1
<---> Index dump: 2
<---> Index dump: 2
<---> Index dump: 3
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 4
<---> Index dump: 5
<---> Index dump: 23
<---> Index dump: 23
<---> Index dump: 22
<---> Index dump: 4
<---> Index dump: 26
<---> Index dump: 6
<---> Index dump: 7
<---> Index dump: 7
<---> Index dump: 8
<---> Index dump: 26
<---> Index dump: 9
<---> Index dump: 34
<---> Index dump: 10
<---> Index dump: 10
<---> Index dump: 11
<---> Index dump: 9
<---> Index dump: 12
<---> Index dump: 25
<---> Index dump: 13
<---> Index dump: 13
<---> Index dump: 14
<---> Index dump: 12
<---> Index dump: 13
<---> Index dump: 25
<---> Index dump: 31
<---> Index dump: 31
<---> Index dump: 15
<---> Index dump: 13
<---> Index dump: 28
<---> Index dump: 33
<---> Index dump: 16
<---> Index dump: 36
<---> Index dump: 33
<---> Index dump: 35
<---> Index dump: 31
<---> Index dump: 24
<---> Index dump: 15
<---> Index dump: 17
<---> Index dump: 25
<---> Index dump: 18
<---> Index dump: 18
<---> Index dump: 25
<---> Index dump: 12
<---> Index dump: 27
<---> Index dump: 34
<---> Index dump: 9
<---> Index dump: 2
<---> Index dump: 1
<---> Index dump: 19
<---> Index dump: 30
<---> Index dump: 32
<---> Index dump: 20
<---> Index dump: 29
<---> Index dump: 25
<---> Index dump: 17
<---> Index dump: 17
<---> Index dump: 21
<---> Index dump: 29
<---> Index dump: 32
<---> Index dump: 26
<---> Index dump: 8
<---> Index dump: 8
<---> Index dump: 20
<---> Index dump: 32
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
<---> Index dump: 0
```

This can be seen as the correct 72 values being copied in and 72 0's being copied in behind it. Did I do something wrong in the copying of my buffer or does this indicate a problem elsewhere?

A further explanation:

Mesh 1 - 72 indices
Mesh 2 - 300 indices
Mesh 3 - 45 indices.

Using the function above, it produces a buffer that does this:

[0]-[71] - Mesh 1 vertices all correct
[72]-[142] - Empty
[142]-[EndofBuffer] - Mesh 2

It creates duplicate sizes filled with 0's.

Comment: You say that there should only be 72 values.  Are you sure that `fragMap[0x36]` is 72 during this loop?  If it were greater than the number of elements in `zmeshes`, it would read past the end of `zmeshes` and write junk values to `iboData` and `vboData`.  Alternately, the code that generated that index dump could be the one looping too many times.  I'd check the value of the loop condition in both the loop above and in the one that generates the index dump, and confirm that they both match the number of elements that you're trying to copy from `zmeshes`.

Comment: @JoshTownzen fragMap is a map which keeps the number of fragments. I was looking for 0x36 fragments. The problem lies with the fact that every time I copy in the buffer, it is copying it in 'x' places past where it should where x is the size of the previous buffer. I updated my post to be more clear.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "I was looking for 0x36 fragments", do you mean that you're looking for as many fragments as are listed in element 0x36 of `fragMap`?  If so, I'd still suggest debugging the value of `fragMap[0x36]` to ensure that it contains the number that you're looking for.  If instead you meant that you were looking for a literal 0x36 fragments (54, in decimal), then that's not what the loop above will do.

Comment: @JoshTownzen That is correct. It returns the number of 0x36 fragments. 0x36 in this case is the type which in my map returns the number of type 0x36 fragments. I fixed the issue. Solution is below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `iboData` is a `GLushort*`, then `iboData+iboPos` actually points to the memory location `(int)iboData + iboPos * sizeof(GLushort)`.  You're confusing byte offsets with array offsets.  In your two `+=` statements, don't multiply by the `sizeof` you used in `memcpy`, as `iboPos` records the `GLushort` offset, not the byte offset.

Answer (score 0):

Keith Randall had the right solution. I was confusing the two. Here is what I ended up doing:

```
// Create the VBO and IBO
    for(int i = 0; i < fragMap[0x36]; i++)
    {
        // Copy the data to the IBO
        memcpy(&iboData[iboPos], zmeshes[i].indices, zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3 * sizeof(GLushort));//sizeof(*zmeshes[i].indices));

        // Advance the position
        iboPos += zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3;

        // Copy the data to the VBO
        memcpy(&vboData[vboPos], zmeshes[i].vertices, zmeshes[i].numVert * sizeof(Vertex));//sizeof(*zmeshes[i].vertices));

        // Advance the position
        vboPos += zmeshes[i].numVert;

        errorLog.writeSuccess("Build log: VBO size %i VBO pos %i IBO size %i IBO pos %i", zmeshes[i].numVert * sizeof(Vertex), 
                              vboPos, zmeshes[i].numPoly * 3 * sizeof(GLshort), iboPos);
    }
```

I wanted the offset into the array. Not the offset into the buffer.