# Sending and receiving strings over TCP socket separately

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP server and client, with an established socket. Let's say I have the following case:

SERVER:

```
char *fn = "John";
char *ln = "Doe";

char buffer[512];

strcpy(buffer, fn);
send(*socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
strcpy(buffer, ln);
send(*socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

CLIENT:

```
char *fn;
char *ln;

char buffer[512];

bytes = recv(*socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
buffer[bytes] = '\0';
strcpy(fn, buffer);

bytes = recv(*socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
buffer[bytes] = '\0';
strcpy(ln, buffer);

printf("%s", fn); 
printf("%s", ln);
```

Expected result:
I want to receive each string separately (as I am saving them in different variables), instead the first recv() gets both the fn "John" and ln "Doe" concatenated "JohnDoe", and the program gets stuck on the second recv()... since I've already done the sending.

I tried the following:
 - Adding \0 to the fn and ln strings like so:

```
char *fn = "John\0";
char *ln = "Doe\0";
```

But the problem persisted.

Is there some sort of condition I can impose so each string is received separately?

EDIT TO ADD MORE QUESTIONS:

1) Why does it in certain instances actually send them separately, and others sends them jointly?

2) Should I send() and recv() alternatively maybe? In some other parts of my code, it seems it is self regulating and only receiving the right strings at the right time without me having to check. Does this do the trick?

3) About sending a header with the length of the string I am about to send, how do I parse the incoming string to know where to split? Any examples would be great.

4) I will definitely check if I'm getting something bigger than my buffer, thanks for pointing to it.

Edit 2:

5) Since I'm always putting things in a buffer char array of size 512. Shouldn't every send operation take the full size of the buffer even if I am sending a 1 letter string? That's what confusing. I have "John" but I'm putting it in an array of size 512 and sending it, shouldn't that fill up the send buffer, and so the recv() function empties the network buffer by also pulling the whole array of size 512?

Comment: You skipped the very fist step in writing a client/server application -- designing the protocol the client and server will use to exchange information. If you never design a protocol, you can't implement a protocol, and then your code will only work, if it works at all, by luck. Clearly you want to send messages, but TCP is not a message protocol. So what's the message protocol you are using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, when the client calls `recv(*socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);`, it will receive *up to* sizeof(buffer) characters (here, 512) from the network.  This is from the network buffer, and has nothing to do with how many times `send` has been called on the server.  `recv` does not look for `\0` or any other character - it's a binary pull from the network buffer.  It will read either the entire network buffer, or `sizeof(buffer)` characters.

You need to check in the first `recv` to see if it has both the first and last name and handle it appropriately.

You can do so either by having the server send the length of the strings as the first few bytes of a stream (a "header"), or by scanning the received data to see if there are two strings.

You really need to perform checks whenever you call `recv` - what if the string is longer than 512 bytes? Then you need to call `recv` multiple time sto get the string.  And what if you get the first string, and only half of the second string?  Usually these two cases only happen when dealing with larger amounts of data, but I've seen it happen in my own code before, so it's best to incorporate good checks on `recv` even when dealing with small strings like this.  If you practice good coding tactics early on you won't have as many headaches down the road.

Comment: Also, if the strings are long enough it may even be possible that a single read does not return an entire one. The receiving logic must account for that as well

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do is to enclose the sent data with a header.  So you would pass the size of the message, including the size of the message, then on the other side you can figure out how long the message should be.

John is 4 chars, so you have the length, something like "0004John" then you would know when to stop reading.  You may also want to add a command to the header, that is very common.  So for instance, first name might be 1, and second name 2;

"01004JOHN" for instance would be set in the buffer and sent.

To do this, you add items to the buffer, then increment the insertion point in the buffer by the sizeof the values you added.  You can use this to add many parts to the buffer. *Just be sure you dont overrun the size of the buffer.

Remember these examples im giving are not correct, because you dont pass the string representation of the number, just the number, so it would be a long int 1, long int 4 and then chars, or unicode, either way, 4 characters.

Comment: String representation is very ok if you have an ASCII protocol.

Comment: How would I go about sending a long int before sending the string, send() only accepts a (void *) as a third parameter. Also, what I am not understanding is that sizeof() should already be taking care of this size wise no? I'm sending a string it's 8 bytes, shouldn't recv() read 8 bytes and stop?

Comment: you dont send it before, you send buffer, you just fill the buffer, so you can just use pointer arithmetic to  move the buffer insertion point.  here is a sample question with the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680309/c-buffer-combining-adding-extra-empty-values  you simply add the value, then advance hte sizeof the item you just added to the buffer

Answer (score 2):

TCP is stream-oriented, not datagram-oriented. If it was the latter, your stuff would work great. You have the following options:

- use [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCTP)
- use UDP if you can afford losing reliability
- separate the strings in a way you can work with, either by prepending a length tag or so or by adding a `NUL` byte for terminating each string.

For the latter, you would just do `send(*socket, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1, 0);` for including the `NUL` which is here nevertheless, and the sender would repeatedly `recv()` and find a string terminator until it has found 2 strings.

Note that you should take care with `strcpy()`: only use it if you are absolutely sure that the string you are writing to is ok.

Your receiver does

```
bytes = recv(*socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
buffer[bytes] = '\0';
```

That is bad because, if the buffer is full, so `bytes == sizeof(buffer)` (which could happen in more complex situations), `buffer[bytes] = '\0'` writes beyond the buffer. SO use

```
bytes = recv(*socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
```

and you can happily do

```
buffer[bytes] = '\0';
```

.

Answer (score 0):

instead of sizeof(buffer) use strlen(fn); so it will transmit only the exact amount of bytes.. if you need null terminator together use strlen(fn)+1 but don't forget to concatenate null terminator with strcat()

also if you send all the buffer size without cleaning with memset you'll also have rubbish along, so beware that..