# c sending image through socket

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm making a simple http server. So far socket works for html files, now I'm trying to make work images.

This is how I read files:

```
char * fbuffer = 0;
long length;
FILE *f;

if ((f = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
length = ftell(f);
fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
fbuffer = malloc(length);
int total = 0;
if (fbuffer)
{
    while (total != length)
    {
        total += fread(fbuffer, 1, length, f);
    }
}
fclose (f);
```

Then I just send data to socket:

```
char response[20048];
snprintf(response, sizeof(response), "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: %s\nContent-Length: %i\n\n%s", type, (int) strlen(fbuffer), fbuffer);
n = send(newsockfd, response, strlen(response)+1, 0);
```

Why it doesn't work for images? Browser is showing an error `The image “http://127.0.0.1:1050/image.gif” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.` Http response is:

```
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: image/gif
```

The image has 247 bytes. In variables length and total are values 247. Variable fbuffer contains GIF89a(+one char -> some binary square with values 0 0 1 0).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `fbuffer` contains binary data, but you're attempting to treat is as a string by using functions like `strlen` and using the `%s` format specifier to print it.

Since binary data may contain a null byte, this prevents string functions from working on them since they use a null byte to mark the end of a string.

You should instead use functions like `memcpy` to put data into your output buffer.

```
char response[20048];
int hlen;

hlen = snprintf(response, sizeof(response), 
    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: %s\nContent-Length: %d\n\n", type, length);
memcpy(response + hlen, fbuffer, length);

n = send(newsockfd, response, hlen + length, 0);
```

Comment: can you explain me how does that memcpy works? how can it copy HTTP headers if they are saved as int?

Comment: @dontHaveName the `memcpy` function copies the specified number of bytes from one buffer to another.  What is in the buffer doesn't matter.  In this case though we use `snprintf` to build the headers which are text.  This function returned the number of bytes written.  Then we use that value to tell `memcpy` that it should write the binary data that many bytes into the buffer, i.e. after the header.

Comment: I have same problem again. This time I'm reading from stidin like this time I have 2 char variables. I am reading like this `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { a[index] = c; b[index] = c; index++) }`. Then I directly write to socket using `write(newsockfd, &a, strlen(b))`. It display again GIF89a. Why? I dont use any strlen or printf function on `a` variable. Thanks (I might create a new question if you want to).

Answer (score 2):

A string in C ends with the `\0` character. It is likely that the binary representation of your image contains this character somewhere inside the data. This means any use if `%s`, `strlen(..)` etc will simply stop at the `\0` character and thus cannot be used for binary data.

Comment: hmm, interesting thanks and the solution is to change fbuffer to some other type?

Comment: @dontHaveName: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656702/sending-and-receiving-strings-over-tcp-socket-separately for the way to go.

Comment: couldn't found an answer there but @dbush already answered me. Thanks to both. It works.